# wp loged in methods doesnt working like signon ord set cookie

Tags: wordpress

hi everyone im trying to fix a bug in a wordpress site
problme is when i try to register new users it works but they didnt logged in or it takes some time to displays a user loged in

this is my func and last method i used

```
    public function verifyCode() {
        $phone = $this->_preparePhoneNumber();

        $this->_verifyOtp( $phone );

        $user = get_user_by( 'login', $phone );
        $isRegistration = false;
        $user_password = wp_generate_password();
        if ( ! $user ) {
            $userId = wp_create_user( $phone, $user_password, $phone . '@persiapartstore.com' );
            $user = new WP_User( $userId );
            $user->set_role( $_POST['isVendor'] ? 'seller' : 'customer' );
            $isRegistration = true;
            $credentials = array(
                'user_login' => $phone,
                'user_password' => $user_password,
                'remember' => true,
            );
            $user = wp_signon( $credentials, false );

        } else {
            $userId = $user->ID;
            wp_set_current_user( $userId );
            wp_set_auth_cookie( $userId );
        }




        wp_send_json_success( [ ...$this->_getLoginResponse( $user ), 'isRegistration' => $isRegistration ] );
    }
```

by the way my login is working when user is existed
but when i create a new user it doesnt logged in
thnaks for your helps

and wp cookie is set in my browser after register but when i try is_user_logged_in() it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

You're using wp_set_current_user and wp_set_auth_cookie for existing users, but not for new users. These functions are crucial for setting the current user and there are many things that needs to fix, I have revised your code, please check

```
public function verifyCode() {
    $phone = $this->_preparePhoneNumber();

    $this->_verifyOtp( $phone );

    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $phone );
    $isRegistration = false;

    if ( ! $user ) {
        $user_password = wp_generate_password();
        $userId = wp_create_user( $phone, $user_password, $phone . '@persiapartstore.com' );
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $userId ); // Reload user data
        $user->set_role( $_POST['isVendor'] ? 'seller' : 'customer' );
        $isRegistration = true;
        
        wp_set_current_user( $userId );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $userId, true ); // Set the login cookie
    } else {
        $userId = $user->ID;
        wp_set_current_user( $userId );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $userId );
    }

    wp_send_json_success( [ ...$this->_getLoginResponse( $user ), 'isRegistration' => $isRegistration ] );
}
```

Comment: thanks, recently i found that when i activate db cach in w3 plugin  
it doesnt set a specific dokan cookie it seem necessaire 
to logged in users 
doesnt save in browser but when i deactivate db cach dokan cookie set in browser and user logged in succesfully